# Merge 2 single row csv files in a sinle row file by command line

Tags: shell, csv, ubuntu, command-line, merge

I have 2 csv file: **a.csv** and **b.csv**. Each file contain a single row of comma spaced numbers. I want to merge the 2 files in a single file with a single row, i.e. to put the row of
**b.csv** after the last value of **a.csv**. 
The command  `cat a.csv b.csv > ab.csv` create a file **ab.csv** with 2 row; is there another command that I can use to merge the 2 files content on a single row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the command `paste a.csv b.csv > c.csv` does exactly what I was asking for.

If you don't want the tab between the 2 row add the option `-d \0` (for more detail see `man paste`)